# How to make a react app change according to the browser size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm writing a code for a UI for a certain group, and i have the following code:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import HRLOGO from './images/highradius-logo-3.png';
import ABCLOGO from './images/Group 20399.png';

export default class App extends Component 
{
  state = {};
  render() 
  {
    return (
      <div className="Bod">
        <div>
          <img src={HRLOGO} alt="" className="container-div"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={ABCLOGO} alt="" className="container-div2"/>
        </div>
        <Helmet>
          <style>{'body { background-color: #2d4250; }'}</style>
        </Helmet>
        <div>
          <h1 className="InvoiceStyle">Invoice List</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="Rectangle">
        </div>
        <div className="search">
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            label="Search Customer ID"
          />
        </div>
        <footer className="Privacy">
          <p>
            Pivacy Policy
          </p>
        </footer >
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}
.Rectangle {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #293d48;
  position: fixed;
  top: 165px;
}
.container-div {
  display: flex;
  height: 8vh;
  width: 20vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  right: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
.InvoiceStyle {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 25px;
}
.container-div2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 8vh;
  width: 20vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 7px;
  left: 15px;
}
.Privacy {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 700px;
  left: 600px;
}
.search {
  position: fixed;
  top: 175px;
  left: 600px;
  width: 20%;
  /* height: 40px; */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: rgb(11, 68, 253);
}

.App-link {
  color: #ff0000;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

How do i make it such that the images and text change according to the aspect area of the platform it is being viewed it? For example, normally on a 16:9 ratio it looks like this:
[image: Normally:]

When browser size changes:
[image: When size changed:]

How do I prevent this? Any help would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `margin:auto;`?

Comment: It does help a bit, but the image size changes instead. Would like the ratio to keep the same if possible- plus this wouldn't work for abc logo, margin:auto would make it go to the centre, which is undesired. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You can use the aspect ratio property

Comment: Sorry but I'm relatively new to this, can you add a comment or some documentation explaining this?

Comment: Update: I added object-fit:cover but that seems to hide the extra parts to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Worked with position: relative and results are very close to the answer. Still don't understand why top won't respond to % but does to px.